# What is the register cache and what does it have to do with const variables?

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-optimization, cpu-registers, pointer-aliasing

From http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.14:

> Even if the language outlawed `const_cast`, the only way to avoid flushing the register cache across a `const` member function call would be to solve the aliasing problem (i.e., to prove that there are no non-`const` pointers that point to the object).

What is the register cache, what does it mean to flush it *across* a `const` member function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is talking about something like this:

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    A * m_a;
    B(A * a) : m_a(a) {}
}; 

Class A {
public:
    int m_num;
    A(int num=0) : m_num(num) {}
    void DoSomethingConst(B * someB) const;
};

void SomeOtherFunction()
{
   A myA;
   B myB(&myA);

   //do something with myA.m_num (1)
   myA.DoSomethingConst(&myB);
   //do something else with myA.m_num (2)
}
```

Inside of `SomeOtherFunction`, the compiler can not save the value of `myA.m_num` in a register during (1) and use it again during (2).  Even though `DoSomethingConst` is `const` and therefore should not change the value of `myA.m_num`, the value could still be changed because there is a non-const pointer to `myA` inside of `myB` and so `myA.m_num` could still change during `myA.DoSomethingConst`.  In this case it is trivial to prove that there is a non-const reference to `myA`, in the general case it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Here "register cache" means having the compiler store values in registers.

Calling a `const` member function should not change the values of any member variables, so if some of them are stored in registers those values would still be valid when the function returns.

Not a very important optimization, I guess.